# How to Setting Up Sublime Text 2 For Spring and Hibernate Development

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, sublimetext2

I am currently using with Sublime Text 2, and I'm working HTML, CSS, JS, JQuery and Java with this platform. But now i want to setup JSF, Spring, and Hibernate using  Sublime Text 2. I have looked at documentation but nothing is working for me.

First I install **Package control** into ST2 and then install Java. Any one have a idea for configuring JSF, Spring, and Hibernate.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you want Sublime to do things beyond its reach. What do you expect it to do with a JSF-Spring-Hibernate project?

Comment: Add auto completion option to Sublime